# how to add code php in wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins

how to add code php in wordpress plugins
I want to put tag

```
function country_registration($name=’Select registration’){
$return = ‘_______________Here________________________’;

return $return;
}
```

Example Code

```
$sql=”SELECT * FROM plan WHERE id = ‘”.$q.”‘”;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo”<div class=’container’>”;
echo “<select name=’Name’>”;
echo “<option>” . $row['Name'] . “</option>”;
echo “</select>”;
echo “<br />”;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function country_registration($name='Select registration', ){

$return = '';

$sql="SELECT * FROM plan WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $return .= "<div class=’container’>";
    $return .= "<select name=’Name’>";
    $return .= "<option>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
    $return .= "</select>";
    $return .= "<br />";
}
return $return;
}
```

note: don't use mysql_query or mysql_fetch_array, use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instead
also, this actual example won't work, as the database connection is out of scope.
you could pass the connection into the function

```
$conn = mysql_connect(etc, etc);

function country_registration($name='Select registration', $conn ){
  // etc    
}
```

or any other methods to get the database connection to work (I suggest making a database object with public methods and using that, but that is outside the scope of the question)

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you can code for plugin in Wordpress. 
1. `functions.php`
2. Create a folder in plugins folder, inside that folder. Create a blank .php file, and code there.